# Adding calls inside QgraphicsRectItem subclass triggers infinite redraw

Tags: qt, inheritance, paint

I have a hierarchy of object types, inheriting from a custom interface and `QGraphicsItem`.

In hope of optimizing the code, I would like to inherit from `QGraphicsSomethingItem`. Example: rectangle

```
class RectangleItem : public Item, public QGraphicsItem
{
  RectangleItem() : Item()  // Item initializes m_pen, m_brush
  {
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable  |
         QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable    |
         QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
  }
  QRectF RectangleItem::boundingRect() const
  {
      return QRectF(-50, -50, 100, 100);
  }
  void RectangleItem::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
  {
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    setItemPen();   // calculates m_pen in class Item
    setItemBrush(); // calculates m_brush in class Item
    painter->setPen(m_pen);
    painter->setBrush(m_brush);
    painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
  }
}
```

This works perfectly.

Now trying the same thing but inheriting from `QGraphicsRectItem`

```
class RectangleItem : public Item, public QGraphicsRectItem
{
  RectangleItem() : Item()  // Item initializes m_pen, m_brush
  {
    setRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable  |
         QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable    |
         QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
  }
  QRectF RectangleItem::boundingRect() const
  {
      return QRectF(-50, -50, 100, 100);
  }
  void RectangleItem::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
  {
  //  setItemPen();   // calculates m_pen in class Item
  //  setItemBrush(); // calculates m_brush in class Item
    setPen(m_pen);
    setBrush(m_brush);
    QGraphicsRectItem::paint(painter, option, widget);
  }
}
```

This creates an infinite loop
- a breakpoint on `setItemPen()` showed it kept calling it. So I removed it, along with `setItemBrush()`. (though I really need to set custom pen)
- a breakpoint on `setPen()` showed it kept calling it. So I removed it. Same with `setBrush()`
- once there were no things being "set" inside paint, the paint worked.

Of course this is not functional - I need to be able to set item properties, and my understanding is that the call to `paint()` - happening when a call to update the scene - would update he items. After all, my first example, inheriting from `QGraphicsItem`, works.

I have found something similar in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17338910/1217150) - but no answer on how to fix it, or no actual explanation why the call to set pen and brush causes a redraw. There is nothing in that code using any of the item's drawing properties, and even more - if I call `setPen(m_pen)` with the value from constructor, I see nothing to be recalculated...

What triggers the object redraw and how can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `QGraphicsRectItem::setPen` and `QGraphicsRectitem::setBrush` set item properties and thus trigger an update and re-enter your `paint`. They *have* to do just that, after all, you asked to change the item! So, any time you change the pen or the brush of a shape, the shape will get re-painted automatically. That's the desired behavior.

If you want to set the pen and the brush on the painter, just do so. Otherwise, set the item's properties *before* you attempt to paint. Remember that the pen and brush are *separate* properties of the item *and* of the painter's state. When talking of them, you must be explicit which one you talk about. The code below illustrates this.

Perhaps you simply want to set the pen/brush on the painter:

```
...
painter->setPen(m_pen);
painter->setBrush(m_brush);
...
```

Remember, an implementation of paint **must never** make any changes to the item!

Here's an example showing:

1. How you can add your own elements when painting a `QGraphicsRectItem`.
2. That `setPen` triggers an automatic repaint.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QTimer>

class XRectItem : public QGraphicsRectItem {
   void paint(QPainter *p, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *opt, QWidget *wdg = 0)
   Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
   {
      QGraphicsRectItem::paint(p, opt, wdg);
      // optional
      if (false)
        p->setPen(QPen(QColor(rand() % 256, rand() % 256, rand() % 256), 0.1));
      p->drawEllipse(rect());
   }
public:
   XRectItem(qreal x, qreal y, qreal w, qreal h, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0) :
      QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, w, h, parent) {}
};

class View : public QGraphicsView
{
   void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      fitInView(sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
   }
public:
   View(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent = 0) :
      QGraphicsView(scene, parent) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QGraphicsScene s;
   XRectItem rect(-1.5, 1.5, 3, 2);
   s.addItem(&rect);
   QTimer timer;
   timer.start(100);
   QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&rect]{
      rect.setPen(QPen(QColor(rand() % 256, rand() % 256, rand() % 256), 0.1));
   });
   View v(&s);
   v.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
   v.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: @Thalia I don't know what's the problem then. What are you trying to do, that you can't do? Of course if you have some code in `Item` that makes it a mixin class, you have to code it such that it acts as it should. For example, it should schedule an update when the attributes change! i think your question is: "How do I implement a QGraphicsItem mixin", maybe...

Comment: @Thalia You were asking why the code crashed when you inherited from `QGraphicsRectItem`. I showed you why. If you didn't mean to ask about it, why did you even put that in the question? Anyway, if you have other questions, ask them separately. Please. And I still mean **You should never need to manually force a repaint of a view/scene! If you do, you're not implementing your items correctly.** Your `Item` mixin is wrongly implemented if it doesn't schedule repaints when necessary.

Comment: @Thalia When you ask a new question, please include *complete, compileable code*, not some fragments. As you can see from the answer, it's possible to be functional, complete and concise. Such code belongs in your questions.

Comment: I understand what you say. I banged my head against the wall about the item requesting an update, and I thought I found the solution:  calling a `scene->viewport()->update()` or something allows me to not call the update explicitly and get the repaint. I'll work on it some more. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Thalia Is `dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem>(this)->update()` what you're looking for? When you do mixins in C++, I'd call this almost an idiom to get access to the derived class.

Comment: @Thalia Yes, that's what it's for! I think you should first implement a stand-alone `QGraphicsItem` *correctly*, and only then turn it into a mixin class. Doing both at once conflates the problems of incorrect QGraphicsItem implementation with those of C++ design/patterns. `QGraphicsItem::update` is there for a reason, you must use it - somehow, but you must.